# Field value set using reflection from listner class is set to null when corresponding test class is executed

Tags: java, reflection, testng

I am working on testng java and trying to set value of a test class field using reflection from listner class. The value is set and retrieved successfully from listner class but produces null when utilizing the same variable field in `@Test` method

```
@Listners(Testrunner.class)
public class testclass{
    String strvalue;
   
    @Test
    public void m1(){
      Sysout(strvalue)------> produces null when testng runs @test method but not testvalue
    }
}

Testrunner implements ITestListener{

  @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestContext arg0) {
        testclass cls = new testclass();
        Field f1 =  testclass.class.getDeclaredField("strvalue");
        f1.setaccessible(true);
        f1.set(cls,"testvalue");
        Sysout(f1.get(cls));---------> i am able to get the value s "testvalue"
        
    }
}
```

Am i missing any logic in this code, help me in complete this

Comment: You are changing the value of a temporary `testclass` instance you just created within `onTestStart` and abandon at the end. Of course, a different object of the same class won’t be affected.

Comment: is there a possible way to set value of the original class ??

Comment: You are mixing up *classes* and *objects*. I don’t know whether TestNG provides access to the test object, check the API documentation of the `ITestContext` argument, as that would be the natural pointer for such a functionality, if it is supported.

Comment: Yes you are right, i got confused with reflection temp objects. ITextContext has access to the test object using getInstance() method. Instead of creating class object i work around as below which works perfectly 

Field f = arg0.getAllTestMethods()[0].getInstance().getClass().getDeclaredField("strvalue")
f.setAccessible(true);
f.set(arg0.getAllTestMethods()[0].getInstance(), "yes i found");